# WCF hosted with Docker file not found if publish for "Any CPU"

Tags: wcf, docker

I'm trying to host `WCF` with Docker. The problem is that the `WCF` is built for `32bit`. First of all I tried to configure the `IIS` to enable 32bit app on 64 bit (there is attribute in the config) but without success. Tried with this in my `Dockerfile`

```
# install WCF basic docker image

FROM microsoft/wcf

# Next, this Dockerfile creates a directory for your application
WORKDIR BookingApi

# configure the new site in IIS.
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command \
Import-module IISAdministration; \
New-IISSite -Name "BookingApi" -PhysicalPath C:\BookingAPI -BindingInformation "*:83:" \
Set-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement "BookingApi" -AttributeName "enable32bitAppOnWin64" -AttributeValue "True"


# This instruction tells the container to listen on port 83. 
EXPOSE 83

# The final instruction copies the site you published earlier into the container.
COPY BookingApi/ .
```

But It fails to build it. So I decided to publish the service with `Any CPU` and through `visual studio` it works and responses, but if I use these files and host them via `Docker` I get `404 - File or directory not found.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The 32 bit configuration option is for the app pool and can be accomplished as follows. There is undoubtedly a PowerShell equivalent.

```
RUN c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:"True" /commit:apphost
```